# How can I put $(SRCROOT) into a string?

Tags: c++, xcode4, environment-variables

Or is there any other way of getting the project's directory into a string? I have tried this

```
const char* filepath = std::getenv("SRCROOT");
```

But filepath shows up as null, it works on other environment variables though. Does SRCROOT have some kind of in-code alias? I can't just use "../", I need the full path in a string.

Comment: It's possible that SRCROOT is not defined in the executing environment.

Comment: int i = 0;
while(environ[i]) {
  printf("%s\n", environ[i++]);
}

Comment: where has environ come from?

Comment: what is the requirement?  <pre>__FILE__ can be useful.

Answer (score 1):

The best option I've found is to define the macro under `Other C Flags` on your project properties according to ${SRCROOT} env variable. Here's how :

[image]

Than you can use the `SRCROOT` on your C/C++ code as constant string.

Answer (score 0):

As for the *project's* directory, check your IDE documentation for environment variables.  It may have a translation that will create a macro with the *project's* directory.

The *executable's* directory can usually be obtained from the first parameter *passed* to the `main` function.

Otherwise project directories, especially directory structures, are platform dependent.  Some platforms, such as embedded systems, don't have directories, only memory.  Consult your operating system for more information.

As an alternative, you may be able to have your *build system* pass the project name as a `define` on the command line.  Other ideas are to create environment variables or configuration files; all should be done by the *build system*.